# How can I specify connect and read timeout for javax.xml.ws Web Service client?

Tags: java, web-services, applet, axis

I have an applet that issues web service calls (I believe AXIS2 ) and I need to set a connect and read timeout values.

My searches returned

```
((BindingProvider)myservice).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties, 60 * 1000);
```

and

```
((BindingProvider)myservice).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 60 * 1000);
```

These probably work for CXF (com.sun.xml.ws) but not for AXIS (javax.xml.ws).  Switching stacks is not an option.

Has anybody set up connect and read timeouts in an AXIS WS client?